# Why "int & const" compiles fine with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, language-lawyer

Consider the following code:

```
int a = 1;
/* Note that const is on the right here */
int & const b = a;
```

For sure, it makes no sense (because reference is like non null *constant* pointer), but this code compiles fine with MSVC 2015 and MSVC 2017. GCC and Clang fail to compile this, as expected:

> error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int&’

Was that intended? Is this a bug?

```
int a = 1;
int const const const & const const const const b = a;
```

This code also compiles fine.

Comment: People who down vote this, please, consider leaving a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't compile *fine*. My Visual C++ says (and that's just compiled with `/nologo /EHsc`, no extra warnings, no `/permissive-`):

```
warning C4227: anachronism used: qualifiers on reference are ignored
```

In your second example, it *also* says:

```
warning C4114: same type qualifier used more than once
```

What more do you want? It's apparently not a bug because the wrong code is explicitly recognised. The compiler probably accepts it to avoid trouble with legacy code, but as long as diagnostic messages are produced, the compiler behaves in a perfectly standards-compliant way. It's up to you not to ignore warnings, and it's up to you to treat them as errors if you want (Visual C++ also has a compiler flag to do that for you).

Comment: I used [online compiler](http://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_visual). It's 19.00.23506.

Comment: @ivaigult: Thanks for adding this information; I removed the paragraph about a possibly outdated compiler. As for the online compiler website, note the check box which says "Show compiler warnings". Tick it and you'll get the warnings above.

Comment: I don't understand why it's warning. The standard says that "cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef-name". And ill-formed means that it doesn't belong to language grammar.

Comment: @ivaigult: The standard formally makes no difference between warnings and errors. If the compiler prints a diagnostic message, then it doesn't matter if it also produces a binary or not. The diagnostic message alone is enough to satisfy standards-compliance. See also §4.1/2.2: *"If a program contains a violation of any diagnosable rule [...], a conforming implementation shall issue at least one diagnostic message."* If that still isn't enough for you, just use the `/WX` flag and you'll get errors.

Comment: @ivaigult In the end, standard is just a piece of paper. MSVC violates standard in many places due to bugs, legacy code support and other reasons.

Comment: @Ivan: The ISO standard is not "just a piece of paper" but an important international contract. Microsoft are active participants in the standardisation process, and their compiler is getting better and more standards-compliant every year. It does violate the standard in some places due to bugs and other reasons, but not for the two cases cited by the OP, for which the compiler correctly prints diagnostic messages, even quite good ones.

Comment: @ChristianHackl It IS just a piece of paper. And this example only proves my point. Standard barely defines anything and everyone is free to ignore and violate it in any way imaginable for reasons like bugs, backward compatibility, bugs maintained for backward compatibility and sometimes because "standard commitee is full of morons and we know better". And I am not even talking about mirriads of undefined behaviors. As for MSVC, it doesn't fully support C++98 and will _never_ be able to support it at this point (for compatibility). So no, standard IS just a paper.

Comment: @Ivan: This example doesn't prove your point, because, as I tried to explain before, MSVC **adheres** to the standard by printing a diagnostic message. Second, C++98 is a very bad example, because **no** compiler except of Comeau ever implemented it fully, thanks to the nearly unimplementable `export` feature, which was subsequently removed from C++. Your *"standard commitee is full of morons and we know better"* quote lacks a citation. You didn't just made it up, did you? Since Microsoft are *on* the committee, I doubt they'd insult themselves. See https://isocpp.org/std/the-committee

Comment: @ChristianHackl No, I was quoting GCC developers. There are many broken things aside from `export`. As for standard conformance - there is no reason to accept this syntax, with or without diagnostic message. This is  just another **bug** turned into a **feature**. Following "the word" of the standard is _highly overratted_, because the result of those word games is always a horrible and unmaintainable crap - the essence of C++. There is a good reason why so many big C++ projects basically ban the whole standard library - it has always beenn unmaintainable and non-portable mess.

Comment: @Ivan: So the conclusion of this rant is that Microsoft are taking the standard very serious and you aren't. Case closed.

Comment: @ChristianHackl If they would, they wouldn't have so many bugs in their compiler and their standard library wouldn't be so horribly broken.